# Can I implement a constant in such a way that every function of it gets redirected?

Tags: matrix, function-construction, algebra

Basically, I want to implement split-complex numbers and tessarines.

They can be easily implemented as 2x2 matrices with complex elements.

But I want them to work in general expressions.

So I want a constant `J` such that ANY function on this constant be redirected into `MatrixFunction` on matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
And after calculations the matrices of the form $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$ converted back to numbers `a + b J`.

Is it possible? I do not want to re-define operations on `J`, but want all the operations to be calculated using the matrix form but so that this would be hidden from the user.

Comment: Have you heard of `UpValues`? For the most part those should work

Comment: @b3m2a1 I already found an answer, see below: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241582/651

Comment: I understand that, but overloading `$Pre` can be dangerous if you forget about it or if someone else is trying to use your code. `UpValues` are much kinder/safer in that regard

Comment: @b3m2a1 I do not know how to do similar things with UpValues. If you know, I welcome other answers.

Comment: Note that the result of `MatrixFunction[f, {{a, b}, {b, a}}][[1]] . {1, J}` shows a way to interpret the result of applying an arbitrary function to a split-complex number.

Comment: @J.M. yes, I have just amended my previous answer with a new, better method: `$Pre=(#/.J->{-1,1})/.{x_,y_}->(x+y)/2+(J(y-x))/2&;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code based on the code by Daniel Huber seems to work:

```
$Pre = If[FreeQ[#, J], #, Module[{tmp},
      
 tmp = Evaluate[MatrixFunction[Function[J, #], {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]];
       tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {b_, a_}} -> a + J b]] &;

Gamma[J + 3]

7/2 + (5 J)/2
```

P.S. This code is even simpler, but less universal (works with split-complex numbers but not with other hypercomplexes):

```
$Pre = (# /. J -> {-1, 1}) /. {x_, y_} -> (x + y)/2 + (J (y - x))/2 &;
```

Comment: PLeased to hear this. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if the following works for all functions, but it may be a start.

We may check every input if it contains `J`, using `$Pre`. If not, we proceed as usual. If yes, we replace every functions, containing `J` as an argument by  `MatrixFunction` acting on this function. Then we evaluate and replace the matrix again by the form: a + b J:

```
ClearAll[J];
$Pre = If[FreeQ[#, J], #, Module[{tmp},
     tmp = Evaluate[# /.  f_[x1___, J, x2___] :> 
         MatrixFunction[f[x1, #, x2] &, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]];
      tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {b_, a_}} -> a + J b]] &;
```

Comment: When I try ``Log[J + 5]`` it gives ``Log[5]``. And ``Log[I J]`` gives ``- Infinity`` (should be $ij\pi/2$).

Comment: Exp[2J], Exp[2+J] etc also gives wrong results...

Comment: `Log[I J]` is actuall `Log[Times[I,J]]` what boils down to `Log[MatrixFunction[I #1 &, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]` what gives {{-Infinity,..},{..}}, certainly not what to expect. Therefore I think the idea with `MatrixFunction` is too complicated for the general case.

Comment: I think a better idea would be to implement explicit replacement rules for the symbol J

Comment: Log also should be converted to MatrixFunction. Otherwise it is applied per each element separately.

Comment: Maybe we should convert all functions to MatrixFunction?

Comment: "I think a better idea would be to implement explicit replacement rules for the symbol J" - is it possible to implement such a rule that MatrixFunction is always used regardless of whatever function is acted on J (and then conversion from matrix form)?

Comment: Think of `J` as some abstract object that has the same rules (isomorph) like your matrix. Then implement these rules. E.g.: Clear[J]; J /: J^n_ = If[EvenQ[n], 1, J]   If you now say: `J^3`you will get `J`. I think using `MatrixFunction` will lead to a lot of complication. And it shows more clearly, that not the presentation matters, but the structure.

Comment: MatrixFunction can exponentiate J to any power, non-integer, imaginary, etc. The same, with any other function. That's why no set of rules can replace it. For instance, ``Gamma[J+2]=3/2+J/2``. How can I implement rules for any special function available in Mathematica? But MatrixFunction can do it.

Comment: I think the easiest mechanism is to use rules. E.g. here is a rule for genal exponentiation: `J^n_ -> 1/2 (1 + (-1)^n + (1 - (-1)^n) J)`

Comment: What is a rule for general Gamma function? Zeta function? PolyGamma function?

Comment: I do not want to convince what to do. I simply point out that there is trouble ahead with MatrixFunction. And MatrxiFunctiion can not with the function you mention.

Comment: MatrixFunction can do all these functions, easily. And numerical calculations as well. That's why we know that $\Gamma(j+3)=7/2+5/2j$, $\zeta(j+1)=\frac{1}{12} \left(\pi ^2-3\right)+\frac{j}{12} \left(3+\pi ^2\right)$, $\psi(j+2)=\frac{3}{4}-\gamma+3/4j$ etc.

Comment: I simply think it is impossible to implement just any special function on arbitrary tessarine as a rule. Especially if such machinery already exists, only in different form.

Comment: This code seems to work: ``$Pre = If[FreeQ[#, J], #, Module[{tmp},
          
     tmp = Evaluate[MatrixFunction[Function[J, #], {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]];
           tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {b_, a_}} -> a + J b]] &;
Log[J]``

Comment: Wrote my own answer, based on yours. Works perfectly!

Comment: @DanielHuber I think you can do this through `UpValues` without needing to overload `$Pre`